# Splashscreen API not showing icon

Tags: android, androidx, android-12

We are currently implementing a splashscreen via the new Splashscreen API. We are following the [migration guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen/migrate). The background color is set correctly (by `windowSplashScreenBackground`), but the icon is not visible, neither on an Emulator, nor on a physical device.

**build.gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0-alpha01"
    ...
}
```

**values-v31/themes.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/AppThemeCompat</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@mipmap/ic_launcher</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">200</item>
</style>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    ...
</application>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    androidx.core.splashscreen.SplashScreen.Companion.installSplashScreen()
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I am answering this question directly as we found the solution to our problem within one or two hours that could be saved from other developers:

**Icons set by the Splashscreen API do not work when starting an app from Android Studio. If the app gets closed and then restarted, the icon shows correctly.**

This bug might exist due to the early alpha status of this library and will allegedly be fixed in a future version of the Splashscreen API.

Comment: have the same issue, but the icon is never shown, using alpha2 though

Comment: I have the same bug/thing as of version 1.0.0